# How to control user access in MicroStrategy

Tags: microstrategy

There are 4 countries databases (Germany,US,Japan and UK).Structure is designed in such a way that primary database is Germany and secondary database are US,JP,UK.Metrics are created on basis of secondary database.Problem is if we select any metric,then the data is populated of that respective country.(for an example if someone will chosse amount metric of UK then data from UK will get populated) but if no metric is selected then the data is getting populated from Germany (primary database) for UK user as well.
How can we solve this issue.

I am new to MicroStrategy,could you please help me. Is there any filter which we can apply in begining and if yes,how we can achieve it.